# Name [t3://127.0.0.1:7001/weblogic.management.mbeanservers.domainruntime] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [t3:]

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, weblogic, jmx

I have `Tomcat 7.0` that has some Java code that I use to connect to a `Weblogic 12c` server to manage the weblogic server. I can use RMI/IIOP but I cannot use T3. Everyone says make sure the `wlfullclient.jar` file is used and available to the Tomcat classpath. It is. I know because if I remove it the error I get is `"Unsupported protocol: T3"`. And my RMI/IIOP connection does not work. So I just swtiched the IIOP protocol to T3 and I get:

`Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [t3://127.0.0.1:7001/weblogic.management.mbeanservers.domainruntime] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [t3:]`

Looking around at all the online documentation I am  wondering if this means I have to set up a config file on my tomcat. All the context connection info is in the code--host, port, userID, password, etc.

So am confused as to why Tomcat says it cannot find t3 and why it can't bind to the `weblogic.management.mbeanservers.domainruntime` mbean. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting

```
"weblogic.management.remote" as JMXConnectorFactory.PROTOCOL_PROVIDER_PACKAGES
```

in your Environment, plus principal and credentials, then create `new JMXServiceURL(...)` with

```
"service:jmx:t3://localhost:7001/jndi/weblogic.management.mbeanservers.domainruntime"
```

and pass that to `JMXConnectorFactory.connect(serviceUrl, env)`.

Also, `wlthint3client.jar` should be enough for this - but I am not sure about this, it's probably safer to build your own wlfullclient.jar as you did...

Comment: Thanks for your response. I actually have my JMXServiceURL structured that way and I have the weblogic.management.remote as the protocol_provider. It just keeps saying it cant find "t3".

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you generated the wlfullclient.jar and what version of JVM you are using.
Can you make sure you follow the steps mentioned in the below page to generate the jar.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/client/jarbuilder.html

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Yep . . . I followed those instructions . . . only from the 12c docs->[link]http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24378/jarbuilder.htm

Answer (score 0):

Those jar can be deceiving.
Whichever you use, make sure is at the begining at the path, and also you can add this code to check you have everything in place.

> Class<?> cl =
>   Class.forName("weblogic.management.remote.t3.ClientProvider");